# a way to programmatically filter a dashboard

Tags: apex, visualforce, dashboard

I want to be able to filter a dashboard based on a parameter passed into it from another source or page. For example, if I select a customer record from a list, I want to be able to display a dashboard page and filter it based on the customer record id. Are there any examples of visual force pages containing dashboards with filters?